# Hacking training simulator

Tags: security, xss, sql-injection

I've never tried to hack sites. I've just followed security guidelines. Now I want to try to develop more safety.

Is there are any "training sites" with holes and "exercises", with SQL injections, redefining global variables, XSS and other kind of holes. Kind of hacker sandbox.

Comment: A more cynical person might tell you that the entire Internet is training sites, but barring that, perhaps you should just do it yourself -- learn about a vulnerability, implement the vulnerability, exploit your implementation, and consider how your implementation is fixable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Google has just the thing, try [Gruyere](http://google-gruyere.appspot.com/)

> This codelab is built around Gruyere /ɡruːˈjɛər/ - a small, cheesy web application that allows its users to publish snippets of text and store assorted files. "Unfortunately," Gruyere has multiple security bugs ranging from cross-site scripting and cross-site request forgery, to information disclosure, denial of service, and remote code execution. The goal of this codelab is to guide you through discovering some of these bugs and learning ways to fix them both in Gruyere and in general.

Answer (score 9):

Pop across to [this question on vulnerable Operating Systems](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/183/485) at Security Stack Exchange or [this one on vulnerable servers for penetration testing](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/1735/485) (especially [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1735/servers-for-penetration-testing/1739#1739) which has an awesome list)

We have a few questions around this topic or [Security Education](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education) in general, adn as a growing resource for IT and Information Security it could be well worth you popping over.

Snippet of content from over there:

> http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/wargames
>
> WebGoat. WebGoat is a set of
>   deliberately insecure Java server
>   pages
>
> http://www.hackthissite.org/
>
> http://www.smashthestack.org/wargames.php
>
> from their FAQ
>
> ```
> The Smash the Stack Wargaming Network hosts several Wargames. A
> ```
>
> Wargame in our context can be
>   described as an ethical hacking
>   environment that supports the
>   simulation of real world software
>   vulnerability theories or concepts and
>   allows for the legal execution of
>   exploitation techniques. Software can
>   be an Operating System, network
>   protocol, or any userland application.
>   Blockquote
>
> http://www.astalavista.com/page/wargames.html
>
> http://www.governmentsecurity.org/forum/index.php?showtopic=15442
>
> http://www.overthewire.org/wargames/
>
> the list is long... some are up, some
>   not...
>
> Update 26 Feb 2011, i found a nice
>   post from
>   http://r00tsec.blogspot.com/2011/02/pentest-lab-vulnerable-servers.html
>   . Some links might be broken. I copy
>   from there:
>
> Holynix Similar to the de-ice Cd’s and
>   pWnOS, holynix is an ubuntu server
>   vmware image that was deliberately
>   built to have security holes for the
>   purposes of penetration testing. More
>   of an obstacle course than a real
>   world example.
>   http://pynstrom.net/index.php?page=holynix.php
>
> WackoPicko WackoPicko is a website
>   that contains known vulnerabilities.
>   It was first used for the paper Why
>   Johnny Can’t Pentest: An Analysis of
>   Black-box Web Vulnerability Scanners
>   found:
>   http://cs.ucsb.edu/~adoupe/static/black-box-scanners-dimva2010.pdf
>   https://github.com/adamdoupe/WackoPicko
>
> De-ICE PenTest LiveCDs The PenTest
>   LiveCDs are the creation of Thomas
>   Wilhelm, who was transferred to a
>   penetration test team at the company
>   he worked for. Needing to learn as
>   much about penetration testing as
>   quickly as possible, Thomas began
>   looking for both tools and targets. He
>   found a number of tools, but no usable
>   targets to practice against.
>   Eventually, in an attempt to narrow
>   the learning gap, Thomas created
>   PenTest scenarios using LiveCDs.
>   http://de-ice.net/hackerpedia/index.php/De-ICE.net_PenTest_Disks
>
> Metasploitable Metasploitable is an
>   Ubuntu 8.04 server install on a VMWare
>   6.5 image. A number of vulnerable packages are included, including an
>   install of tomcat 5.5 (with weak
>   credentials), distcc, tikiwiki, twiki,
>   and an older mysql.
>   http://blog.metasploit.com/2010/05/introducing-metasploitable.html
>
> Owaspbwa Open Web Application Security
>   Project (OWASP) Broken Web
>   Applications Project, a collection of
>   vulnerable web applications.
>   http://code.google.com/p/owaspbwa/
>
> Web Security Dojo A free open-source
>   self-contained training environment
>   for Web Application Security
>   penetration testing. Tools + Targets =
>   Dojo
>   http://www.mavensecurity.com/web_security_dojo/
>
> Lampsecurity LAMPSecurity training is
>   designed to be a series of vunlerable
>   virtual machine images along with
>   complementary documentation designed
>   to teach linux,apache,php,mysql
>   security.
>   http://sourceforge.net/projects/lampsecurity/files/
>
> Damn Vulnerable Web App (DVWA) Damn
>   Vulnerable Web App is a PHP/MySQL web
>   application that is damn vulnerable.
>   Its main goals are to be an aid for
>   security professionals to test their
>   skills and tools in a legal
>   environment, help web developers
>   better understand the processes of
>   securing web applications and aid
>   teachers/students to teach/learn web
>   application security in a class room
>   environment. www.dvwa.co.uk/
>
> Hacking-Lab This is the Hacking-Lab
>   LiveCD project. It is currently in
>   beta stadium. The live-cd is a
>   standardized client environment for
>   solving our Hacking-Lab wargame
>   challenges from remote.
>   http://www.hacking-lab.com/hl_livecd/
>
> Moth Moth is a VMware image with a set
>   of vulnerable Web Applications and
>   scripts, that you may use for:
>   http://www.bonsai-sec.com/en/research/moth.php
>
> Damn Vulnerable Linux (DVL) Damn
>   Vulnerable Linux is everything a good
>   Linux distribution isn’t. Its
>   developers have spent hours stuffing
>   it with broken, ill-configured,
>   outdated, and exploitable software
>   that makes it vulnerable to attacks.
>   DVL isn’t built to run on your desktop
>   – it’s a learning tool for security
>   students.
>   http://www.damnvulnerablelinux.org
>
> pWnOS pWnOS is on a “VM Image”, that
>   creates a target on which to practice
>   penetration testing; with the “end
>   goal” is to get root. It was designed
>   to practice using exploits, with
>   multiple entry points
>   http://www.backtrack-linux.org/forums/backtrack-videos/2748-%5Bvideo%5D-attacking-pwnos.html
>   http://www.krash.in/bond00/pWnOS%20v1.0.zip
>
> Virtual Hacking Lab A mirror of
>   deliberately insecure applications and
>   old softwares with known
>   vulnerabilities. Used for
>   proof-of-concept /security
>   training/learning purposes. Available
>   in either virtual images or live iso
>   or standalone formats.
>   http://sourceforge.net/projects/virtualhacking/files/
>
> Badstore Badstore.net is dedicated to
>   helping you understand how hackers
>   prey on Web application
>   vulnerabilities, and to showing you
>   how to reduce your exposure.
>   http://www.badstore.net/
>
> Katana Katana is a portable multi-boot
>   security suite which brings together
>   many of today’s best security
>   distributions and portable
>   applications to run off a single Flash
>   Drive. It includes distributions which
>   focus on Pen-Testing, Auditing,
>   Forensics, System Recovery, Network
>   Analysis, and Malware Removal. Katana
>   also comes with over 100 portable
>   Windows applications; such as
>   Wireshark, Metasploit, NMAP, Cain &
>   Able, and many more.
>   www.hackfromacave.com/katana.html

Answer (score 2):

If you're a Java man you should take a look at WebGoat:
http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_WebGoat_Project

If you're more into MySQL/PHP have a look at HackThisSite:
http://www.hackthissite.org/

I've always had a lot of fun with HackThisSite.

Answer (score 1):

Acunetix provides several sites that demonstrate vulnerabilities in various technologies:

http://testphp.vulnweb.com/

http://testaspnet.vulnweb.com